# SiloHost on Kubernetes

Tags: .net, kubernetes, azure-cloud-services, orleans, azure-aks

I am trying to start a  Microsoft Orleans Silo Host on Azure Kubernetes cluster.
My configuration in code is the following

```
var builder = new SiloHostBuilder()
            .Configure<ClusterOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ClusterId = appSettings.OrleansSettings.ClusterId;
                options.ServiceId = appSettings.OrleansSettings.ServiceId;
            })
            .Configure<ClusterMembershipOptions>(opt =>
            {
                opt.ValidateInitialConnectivity = false;
            })
            .UseKubeMembership(opt =>
            {
                opt.CanCreateResources = true;
                opt.DropResourcesOnInit = true;
            })
            .ConfigureEndpoints
            (
                siloPort: appSettings.OrleansSettings.SiloPort,
                gatewayPort: appSettings.OrleansSettings.GatewayPort,
                addressFamily: System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                listenOnAnyHostAddress: true
            )
            .Configure<ProcessExitHandlingOptions>(o =>
            {
                o.FastKillOnProcessExit = true;
            });
```

And I have this on my appsettings.json

```
"AppSettings": {
    "OrleansSettings": {
      "ClusterId": "OrleansCluster",
      "ServiceId": "OrleansService",
      "SiloPort": 11111,
  "GatewayPort": 30000
}
```

The builder builds correctly, but when running the StartAsync method:

```
var host = builder.Build();
await host.StartAsync();
```

I get this error:

```
Couldn't start silohost. Error: Orleans.Runtime.OrleansLifecycleCanceledException: Lifecycle start canceled due to errors at stage 8000 ---> System.TimeoutException: Starting MembershipOracle failed due to timeout 00:05:00
```

And I don't know what the problem seems to be.

Comment: Hello man. Can you please post the full stack trace? I'm unable to identify what is going on in your case. I created and I used that provider daily and it works just fine.

Comment: Hello @Mihai , i am now faced with the same task , to deploy orleans using Kubernetes.Did it work out for you ?